# If text box content is empty, do

Tags: php, text

I got a problem with my code.
I want to figure out if there is a specific number in the text box and if it's empty it should say something like "There's nothing inside".

I did so but got a problem if the text box is empty.
If it's empty it skips the code for checking if it's empty, proceeds with the function after it.

That's what I got so far.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $name = $_POST['winner'];
  if(strpos($name,'123456789') !== false){
   echo "<br><br>".$name." was the correct answer! Congratulations!";
  }elseif($name !== ""){
   echo "<br><br>You haven't typed in a number.";
  }else{
   echo "<br><br>".$name." wasn't correct. Better luck next time.";
  }
 }
?>
```

Anyone know what the error is?

Comment: Can you post your HTML for this too?  Also be sure to sanitize your inputs :)

Comment: You're outputting the message when `$name` is *not* blank.

Comment: Did you mean `===` instead of `!==` ? Also, check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php as it may be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
}elseif($name !== ""){
```

Should be:

```
}elseif ($name === ""){
```

Or:

```
}elseif (!strlen($name)){
```

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. Thank you for your help. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @DarkheartUnique You're welcome; please consider accepting this answer if you don't have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant the opposite.

Should be `elseif($name === "")` not `elseif($name !== "")`

or also `elseif(empty($name))`

Answer (score 0):

you want that if user leave text field empty it again ask for that ...

give me your email I'll mail you an example. ....

Comment: Posting a relevant example here is typically sufficient.